# Declarar const array of variant

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Quando necessito usar const de array normalmente faço assim:

```
    var
      Campos : array [0..2,0..1] of string = (('campoa','AAA'),
                                              ('campob','BBB'),
                                              ('campoc','CCC'));
```

Gostaria de declarar a const acima como of variant.

Exemplo:

```
  var
    Campos : array [0..2,0..1] of variant = (('campoa',ftString),
                                             ('campob',ftInteger),
                                             ('campoc',ftDate));
```

Algum dos senhores teria uma ideia de como devo proceder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se você tem os tipos e os dados serão estruturados, o ideal é fugir do *variant*, como você não quer usar variável, indico *"const array of record"*:

```
type   
   TCampos = record
      CampoA: string;
      CampoB: Integer;
      CampoC: Double;
   end;

const
   cCampos: array[0..2] of TCampos = (
      (CampoA: 'campoa'; CampoB: 1; CampoC: 1.2),
      (CampoA: 'campob'; CampoB: 2; CampoC: 56.9),
      (CampoA: 'campoc'; CampoB: 3; CampoC: 32)
   );

var
   i: Integer;
begin
   for i := 0 to 2 do
   begin
      ShowMessage(Format('CampoA: %s, CampoB: %d, CampoC: %2f',
         [cCampos[i].CampoA, cCampos[i].CampoB, cCampos[i].CampoC]));
   end;
end;
```

Comment: Bom dia @Melissa Obrigado pela sua atenção.  Maneiro a sua dica. O Junior Moreira tinha sujerido usar um TRECORD.. mas não pensei em usar dessa forma que tu demonstrou.. Acho que irá dar certo.. Vou codificar aqui para ver como fica.. :) Obrigado :)

Comment: Boa tarde.. Funcionou perfeitamente para os devidos fins .. obrigado :)

Answer (score 2):

Eu utilizaria um record e depois criaria um Array deste record.

Algo como:

```
var
  i      : Integer;
  Campos : Array of TCampos;
begin
  SetLength(Campos, 10);

  for i := Low(Campos) to High(Campos) do
  begin
    Campos[i].CampoA := 'Aluno';
    Campos[i].CampoB := 1;
    Campos[i].CampoC := Now;
  end;
end;
```

Aqui criei um Array simples de um Record, nada impede que você modifique para uma Matriz.

Comment: bom dia @Júnior Moreira Poderia fazer desse modo também, contudo ai toda vez que usasse a função que utilizaria a CONST teria que montar o array of TCampos e depois le-lo novamente... "muito" processamento..saca?? Com a CONST tipo VARIANT eu só Leio ela para os fins necessários.. me compreende?

Comment: Nos dias atuais "processamento", mesmo que o Array possua 1000 posições vai ser 1/10 piscar de olhos para percorrer. Testando em um "AMD K62 500" o resultado é o mesmo, algo como 3/10 piscar de olhos, entendeu?

Comment: Bom dia @Junior Moreira.  O que quis dizer com "PROCESSAMENTO" foi TRABALHO mesmo :).  Teria que CARREGAR o array toda hora que  fosse usar.. Mas como a nossa colega MELISSA demonstrou acho que a solução que necessito ficara melhor.. mais enchuta.. Estou codificando aqui para ver o resultado final.  Obrigado novamente pela atenção :) Valeu mesmo :)